# How to identify SSL message during data exchange

Tags: c, ssl

I am developing a project in which I have to send encrypted messages from client to server.
I use SSL library to encrypt and decrypt my messages. ( C Language) At the server side, to detect if it is a SSL Handshake message I check the first byte of the message. If it is `0x16`, it implies a SSL Handshake. But the problem I face is, when data exchange is done after the handshake, it can be encrypted or unencrypted. How is it possible to identify whether the incoming messsage is encrypted or not? 
Note: For data exchange the first byte is not `0x16` in SSL.

Comment: "It can be encrypted or unencrypted". Why? Why add this complication? Once you upgrade to SSL, leave it that way. Eliminate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some SSL library on both the ends then handshakes will be taken care of by the library. You don't need to worry about it. Secondly, the communication and data exchange between the SSL enabled end-points do not need explicit encryption/decryption because all data flowing through the SSL channel is always encrypted and the encryption decryption is taken care of between the SSL library. So, explicit encryption/decryption of the data would be redundant in an SSL channel and should not be done.

But, if your end-points switch between SSL and Non-SSL modes then you should take care of explicit encryption of sensitive data in Non-SSL mode.

Comment: How my program works is that, I do a handshake at the start of the program and enable a TLS connection. If a specific condition matches, I encrypt and send the data. The reason it works is because I used to listen for encrypted messages on a separate port. But there is a requirement now to make even encrypted messages be sent on the same port as the one in which normal messages are sent. So even if handshake is established I have to send encrypted and non-encrypted data on the same port. Is it possible?

Comment: Certainly, its possible, if you want so. You need to devise your own protocol to mark the encrypted data so that the other party understands that it is encrypted and should decrypt it to make sense of it. I don't recollect if there exists an out-of-box solution to this. Devising one should not be a hell of a task if you are using XML as the exchange format.

Comment: It is not possible for me to add any specific byte to encrypt the data. I am sending a HTTP GET Request, and it is not allowed for me to add any extra data.

Comment: You certainly can pass metadata to indicate what you need to, in the query string or the HTTP headers.

Comment: @user1692342: you should have mentioned that you are dealing with HTTP messages.  That makes a big difference.  To send separate HTTP and HTTPS messages on the same port, you have to disconnect in between each request so the receiver can then look for the SSL handshake at the beginning of each new connection. The alternative is to not use HTTPS at all, but to instead encrypt just the body of a message using a `Transfer-Encoding` that both parties understand.

Answer (score 0):

Just like a handshake is used to initiate an encrypted session, both parties have to agree and notify each other that they wish to stop using encryption at the same time.  SSL has no provision for that, so it has to be handled in the higher level application protocol instead.  You can't decide to use SSL or ignore it on a per-message basis.  Once SSL is active, everything is encrypted.  That is simply how SSL works. If you really need per-message encryption then you need to use encryption inside of the message content instead of at the transport level where SSL operates.

Comment: How my program works is that, I do a handshake at the start of the program and enable a TLS connection. If a specific condition matches, I encrypt and send the data. The reason it works is because I used to listen for encrypted messages on a separate port. But there is a requirement now to make even encrypted messages be sent on the same port as the one in which normal messages are sent. So even if handshake is established I have to send encrypted and non-encrypted data on the same port. Is it possible?

Comment: Like I said, If you need per-message encryption than SSL is not the right tool for the job.  SSL encrypts the socket connection itself, regardless of the data being exchanged. What you need is unencrypted messages with encrypted payloads instead.